# basic_string implementation of libstdc++ in GCC and custom pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, language-lawyer, stdstring, allocator

I tried to study libstdc++ source code (GCC 7.2) recently and was confused. Probably I have missed something important, but I started to think that it is impossible to implement **basic_string** class that will fully comply C++ standard.

Here is a problem that I have faced.

1. **basic_string** should be able to accept custom allocator class as template parameter.
2. **allocate** method is required as a part of allocator.
3. **allocate** is allowed to return objects of user-defined type that "acts like pointer to allocated data". Let's call it **my_pointer**.
4. **my_pointer** should satisfy only the requirements for **NullablePointer** and **RandomAccessIterator**. All other requirements are optional. According to standard we may be unable to cast **my_pointer** to **CharT*** type (another **basic_string** template parameter) because it is optional.
5. On the other hand **const CharT* c_str()** method should be implemented as a part of the standard, so we have to know how to make this cast.

Items 4 and 5 are conflicting and I don't know how to resolve it.
Hope that you can help me to figure it out.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several requirements from the standard that together always ensure the conversion is possible, at least indirectly

1. Given `basic_­string<charT, traits, Allocator>`, [the standard requires](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.string#string.require-3) `charT` and `allocator_traits<Allocator>::value_type` be equal.
2. `allocator_traits<Allocator>::pointer` [is required](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/allocator.traits#types-1) to be either `Allocator::pointer` or `Allocator::value_type*`.

   - In the former case, given a `Allocator::pointer` `p`, `*p` [is required](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/allocator.requirements#tab:utilities.allocator.requirements) to be `Allocator::value_type&`.
   - In the latter case, everything is trivial.
3. `Allocator::pointer` [is required](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/allocator.requirements#5) to be a [contiguous iterator](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/iterator.requirements.general#6), which requires, given a contiguous iterator `q`, `*(q + n) == *(addressof(*q) + n)`
4. Given an `Allocator` `a`, `a.allocate(n)` [is required](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/allocator.requirements#tab:utilities.allocator.requirements) to return a `Allocator::pointer`.

Combining everything together, it means this is always correct

```
template<typename charT, typename traits = /* ... */, typename Allocator = /* ... */>
class basic_string
{
    typename std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::pointer _data;
    // ...

public:
    charT* c_str() { return std::addressof(*_data); }
    // ...
};
```

Where `_data` possibly stores the result from a previous call to `Allocator::allocate`

Comment: A day may come when I get smarter, but it is not this day. Thank you for help! You answer is very useful.